# getting error from update column from same table using mysql

Tags: mysql

I am updating a table column from same table  field. But i am getting one error.

```
  UPDATE t 
     SET t.date = t2.date 
    FROM date_table t 
    JOIN date_table t2 
      ON t.id = t2.id 
   WHERE t2.status = 'completed' 
     AND t2.id = 969
```

i am getting one error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM cdp_lti_topic_details t JOIN cdp_lti_topic_details t2 ON t.id = t2.' at line 3

Comment: Yep; you can't just make up syntax, and syntax from one RDBMS to another varies.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a syntactically correct query...

```
 UPDATE date_table t 
   JOIN date_table t2 
     ON t.id = t2.id 
    SET t.date = t2.date 
  WHERE t2.status = 'completed' 
    AND t2.id = 969
```